# Accessing certain structure elements in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I am new to Python and having difficulty understanding how to access certain parts of a structure.

If we use the csv module, we can read a *csv* file with the following

```
import csv
with open('a.csv', 'rb') as cf:
cr = csv.reader(cf)
for row in cr:
    row
```

**file > a.csv**

```
Fname, Lname, Country, Age
Jack, SO, Uk, 40
Ivan, Deen, US, 50
```

Running our py script will produce

```
['Fname', ' Lname', ' Country', ' Age ']
['Jack', ' SO', ' Uk', ' 40']
['Ivan', ' Deen', ' US', ' 50']
```

In other languages I would try to access something like

```
row[2]
row['fname'][2]
```

However this doesnt seem to be working, how can I access these elements to work with them? maybe there is a easier/better way than what I am attempting?

Comment: [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

Comment: Where doesn't it seem to be working?

Comment: the first thing is to understand what data structures you're dealing with... in your case above each `row` is a `list` (and first row contains the column names)... so `row[2]` will get second column from the current row but `row['fname'][2]` won't work because a list contains only values, there are no keys like `'fname'`... for that you'd need a dict

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what precisely you want to be doing with the data, but I think your mental model fits better with csv.DictReader rather than csv.reader.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

You can use it as below:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('a.csv', 'rb') as cf:
...     cr = csv.DictReader(cf)
...     for row in cr:
...         print row['Fname'], row['Age']
...
Jack 40
Ivan 50
```

Comment: If you want more sophisticated stuff (like summing along a row, statistics etc.) use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). Otherwise, `csv.DictReader` is the way to go.